# Why is there an extra loop before reaching EOF in this D example?

Tags: io, d

Here is an example from the official D book:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    File file = File("student_records", "w");

    file.writeln("Name  : ", "Zafer");
    file.writeln("Number: ", 123);
    file.writeln("Class : ", "1A");
    file.close();

    File file1 = File("student_records", "r");

    while (!file1.eof()) {
        string line = (chomp(file1.readln()));
        writeln("read line -> |", line);
    }
}
```

If you run it, you get:

```
ldc2 -run file.d
read line -> |Name  : Zafer
read line -> |Number: 123
read line -> |Class : 1A
read line -> |
```

Note there is an empty line printed. Now if I change the third writeln to write,

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    File file = File("student_records", "w");

    file.writeln("Name  : ", "Zafer");
    file.writeln("Number: ", 123);
    file.write("Class : ", "1A");
    file.close();

    File file1 = File("student_records", "r");

    while (!file1.eof()) {
        string line = (chomp(file1.readln()));
        writeln("read line -> |", line);
    }
}
```

then the last empty line is not printed anymore:

```
ldc2 -run file.d
read line -> |Name  : Zafer
read line -> |Number: 123
read line -> |Class : 1A
```

I am wondering why this can make a difference: readln should read to the end of the line including the line termination symbol anyways, and why should there be an extra loop when we obviously have reached EOF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that readln reads up to and including the line terminator (`'\n'`) but not up to EOF. your file looks something like this:

```
Name  : Zafer\n   <---- first readln
Number: 123\n     <---- second readln
Class : 1A\n      <---- third readln
EOF               <---- fourth readln
```

After the third call of `readln`, there is still more to read, even if its just EOF. This last call to`readln` returns null, which `writeln` happily accepts and prints nothing (following the string "read line -> |"). The example given in the [docs on readln](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html#.File.readln) actually checks whether `readln` returns null and uses that to terminate.

```
// Reads $(D stdin) and writes it to $(D stdout).
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    string line;
    while ((line = stdin.readln()) !is null)
        write(line);
}
```

Another option is to use `foreach`:

```
foreach(line ; file1.byLine) {
    writeln("read line -> |", line.chomp);
}
```

Both the above and the example in the docs avoid printing that empty line.

As you describe above, replacing your last `writeln` with `write` when creating the file also avoids printing the last empty line as there is one less `\n`, so the third call to `readln` reads straight through to `EOF` without being stopped at a final `\n`.